# Git ignoring folder App & Resources from my Laravel

Tags: laravel, git, github, gitignore

I'm having a problem in my Laravel app trying to pull it to Github.

All new files in the App and Resources folders are not detected on Github Desktop. When I do the command `git status --ignored`, all new files in the folder are in gitignored.
But I'm not having problems when creating a new file in the Public folder.

But when I change old files, they are detected on Github Desktop.
[image]

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: can you include the `.gitignore` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your App and Resources folders are not part of your .gitignore file.  You can check this by running `cat .gitignore` and viewing the output to see what files are ignored.

If they are ignored by some variation of a regex like `App/**` or `Resources/**` remove them from the .gitignore and then they should be available to stage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I command `cat .gitignore`, here's the response I get.

`$ cat .gitignore
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/public/backend/summernote
app/Http/Controllers/LivescoreController.php
*.php`

As it turned out, all the .php files I created were also not detected on Github Desktop. Even when I create it in the Public folder.

Should I remove *php from the .gitignore file?

Comment: @HafidMaulana yes you should remove that, your software is written in PHP so its kinda important to be able to track the PHP files

Comment: Removing *.php will allow tracking for all .php files not ignored through any of the other regex so you likely want to remove it for your purposes.